# Chart.js: gradient fill to a doughnut chart bar

Tags: chart.js, gradient, background-color

I am trying to apply a background-color gradient fill to my doughnut chart.

I have tried several ways to add a gradient both stored in an array and in a simple variable.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('level_chart');

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: ['Sold', 'Left'],
            datasets: [{
                data: [36, 9],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(80, 93, 247, 0.8)',
                    'rgba(255,255,255 ,1 )'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(80, 93, 247, 1)',
                    'rgba(0,0,0 ,0.7 )'
                ],
                borderWidth: 2.5
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                Axes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        drawBorder: false,
                    },
                }],
            },
            rotation: 1 * Math.PI,
            circumference: 1 * Math.PI,
            tooltips: {
                //enabled: false
                displayColors: false
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            layout: {
                padding: {
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    top: 2,
                    bottom: 35
                }
            },
            cutoutPercentage: 70,
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>


 <canvas id="level_chart"></canvas>
```

The result should be a gradient fill in the first section of the doughnut chart. Similar to this:

```
gradientFill.addColorStop(0, "rgba(80, 93, 247, 0.8)");
gradientFill.addColorStop(1, "rgba(80, 93, 247, 0.4)");
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is possible (at least I couldn't achieve it in the last few hours...). You would need a conic gradient but you can't use that on 2D-canvas. You can use ctx.arc for gradient paths but not for chartjs-backgroundColor.
I would be happy if somebody can correct me...

Comment: @HeadhunterKev your efforts are highly appreciated. thanks man. I will let you know if I figured out how to circumnavigate this issue

Comment: @Jakob did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not...